# Error 1054: Unknown column in field list and where clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I am missing something here, not sure what. please help me.

I am trying to copy the data in vs_smelter_temporary into vs_smelter_ext with a where clause

---

```
use test;
Update vs_smelter_ext
SET vs_smelter_ext.Certification_Status = vs_smelter_temporary.Certification_Status
where 
vs_smelter_ext.Smelter_Id = vs_smelter_temporary.Smelter_Id
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to the temporary table:

```
UPDATE vs_smelter_ext 
     JOIN vs_smelter_temporary ON vs_smelter_ext.Smelter_Id = vs_smelter_temporary.Smelter_Id 
     SET vs_smelter_ext.Certification_Status = vs_smelter_temporary.Certification_Status;
```

Comment: Daniel, i am still getting test.vs_smeler_ext doesn't exist error

Comment: Well, does it exist? you can see what tables exist by using `SHOW TABLES;` Looks like maybe a typo in my example, but you should be able to fix that yourself.